# Qt Connect Signals to Slots

Tags: c++

I am trying to connect a signal. But I keep on encountering this. I am sure that I have linked up the *.h file which contains QAction *actionCameraSetup. Am I missing anything out?

Please help.
Thanks.

Error:

> 1>camera.cpp 1>.\camera.cpp(10) : error C2065: 'actionCamera_Setup' :
>   undeclared identifier

**camera.cpp**

```
#include "camera.h"
#include "camera_setup.h"
#include "ui_camera.h"

Camera::Camera(QWidget *parent, Qt::WFlags flags)
    : QMainWindow(parent, flags)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    connect(actionCamera_Setup, SIGNAL(activated()), this, SLOT(openCameraSetup()));
}

Camera::~Camera()
{

}

void Camera::openCameraSetup()
{
    newCameraSetup = new camera_setup();
    newCameraSetup->show();
}
```

**camera.h**

```
#ifndef CAMERA_H
#define CAMERA_H

#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include "ui_camera.h"
#include "ui_camera_setup.h"

class camera_setup;

class Camera : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    Camera(QWidget *parent = 0, Qt::WFlags flags = 0);
    ~Camera();

public slots:
    void openCameraSetup();

private:
    Ui::CameraClass ui;
    camera_setup *newCameraSetup;
};

#endif // CAMERA_H
```

**ui_camera.h**

```
#ifndef UI_CAMERA_H
#define UI_CAMERA_H

#include <QtCore/QVariant>
#include <QtGui/QAction>
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QtGui/QButtonGroup>
#include <QtGui/QGridLayout>
#include <QtGui/QHeaderView>
#include <QtGui/QLabel>
#include <QtGui/QMainWindow>
#include <QtGui/QMenu>
#include <QtGui/QMenuBar>
#include <QtGui/QWidget>

class QAction;

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE

class Ui_CameraClass
{
public:
    QAction *actionExit;
    QAction *actionCamera_Setup;
    QAction *actionFull_Screen;
    QAction *action1_Camera_1;
    QAction *action1_Camera_2;
    QAction *action1_Camera_3;
    QAction *action1_Camera_4;
    QAction *action1_Camera_5;
    QAction *action1_Camera_6;
    QAction *action2_Camera_1;
    QAction *action2_Camera_2;
    QAction *action2_Camera_3;
    QAction *action2_Camera_4;
    QAction *action2_Camera_5;
    QAction *action2_Camera_6;
    QWidget *centralWidget;
    QGridLayout *gridLayout;
    QLabel *label_CCV;
    QMenuBar *menuBar;
    QMenu *menuFile;
    QMenu *menuView;
    QMenu *menuCameras;

    void setupUi(QMainWindow *CameraClass)
    {
        if (CameraClass->objectName().isEmpty())
            CameraClass->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("CameraClass"));
        CameraClass->resize(600, 367);
        actionExit = new QAction(CameraClass);
        actionExit->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("actionExit"));
        actionCamera_Setup = new QAction(CameraClass);
        actionCamera_Setup->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("actionCamera_Setup"));
        actionFull_Screen = new QAction(CameraClass);
        actionFull_Screen->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("actionFull_Screen"));
        action1_Camera_1 = new QAction(CameraClass);
        action1_Camera_1->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("action1_Camera_1"));
        action1_Camera_2 = new QAction(CameraClass);
        action1_Camera_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("action1_Camera_2"));
        action1_Camera_3 = new QAction(CameraClass);
        action1_Camera_3->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("action1_Camera_3"));
        action1_Camera_4 = new QAction(CameraClass);
        action1_Camera_4->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("action1_Camera_4"));
        action1_Camera_5 = new QAction(CameraClass);
        action1_Camera_5->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("action1_Camera_5"));
        action1_Camera_6 = new QAction(CameraClass);
        action1_Camera_6->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("action1_Camera_6"));
        action2_Camera_1 = new QAction(CameraClass);
        action2_Camera_1->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("action2_Camera_1"));
        action2_Camera_2 = new QAction(CameraClass);
        action2_Camera_2->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("action2_Camera_2"));
        action2_Camera_3 = new QAction(CameraClass);
        action2_Camera_3->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("action2_Camera_3"));
        action2_Camera_4 = new QAction(CameraClass);
        action2_Camera_4->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("action2_Camera_4"));
        action2_Camera_5 = new QAction(CameraClass);
        action2_Camera_5->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("action2_Camera_5"));
        action2_Camera_6 = new QAction(CameraClass);
        action2_Camera_6->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("action2_Camera_6"));
        centralWidget = new QWidget(CameraClass);
        centralWidget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("centralWidget"));
        gridLayout = new QGridLayout(centralWidget);
        gridLayout->setSpacing(0);
        gridLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
        gridLayout->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("gridLayout"));
        label_CCV = new QLabel(centralWidget);
        label_CCV->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("label_CCV"));

        gridLayout->addWidget(label_CCV, 0, 0, 1, 1);

        CameraClass->setCentralWidget(centralWidget);
        menuBar = new QMenuBar(CameraClass);
        menuBar->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("menuBar"));
        menuBar->setGeometry(QRect(0, 0, 600, 21));
        menuFile = new QMenu(menuBar);
        menuFile->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("menuFile"));
        menuView = new QMenu(menuBar);
        menuView->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("menuView"));
        menuCameras = new QMenu(menuView);
        menuCameras->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("menuCameras"));
        CameraClass->setMenuBar(menuBar);

        menuBar->addAction(menuFile->menuAction());
        menuBar->addAction(menuView->menuAction());
        menuFile->addAction(actionExit);
        menuView->addAction(menuCameras->menuAction());
        menuView->addAction(actionCamera_Setup);
        menuView->addSeparator();
        menuView->addAction(actionFull_Screen);
        menuCameras->addAction(action1_Camera_1);
        menuCameras->addAction(action1_Camera_2);
        menuCameras->addAction(action1_Camera_3);
        menuCameras->addAction(action1_Camera_4);
        menuCameras->addAction(action1_Camera_5);
        menuCameras->addAction(action1_Camera_6);
        menuCameras->addSeparator();
        menuCameras->addAction(action2_Camera_1);
        menuCameras->addAction(action2_Camera_2);
        menuCameras->addAction(action2_Camera_3);
        menuCameras->addAction(action2_Camera_4);
        menuCameras->addAction(action2_Camera_5);
        menuCameras->addAction(action2_Camera_6);

        retranslateUi(CameraClass);
        QObject::connect(actionCamera_Setup, SIGNAL(activated()), CameraClass, SLOT(show()));

        QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(CameraClass);
    } // setupUi

    void retranslateUi(QMainWindow *CameraClass)
    {
        CameraClass->setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("CameraClass", "Camera", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        actionExit->setText(QApplication::translate("CameraClass", "Exit", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        actionCamera_Setup->setText(QApplication::translate("CameraClass", "Camera Setup", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        actionFull_Screen->setText(QApplication::translate("CameraClass", "Full Screen", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        action1_Camera_1->setText(QApplication::translate("CameraClass", "1 Camera 1", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        action1_Camera_2->setText(QApplication::translate("CameraClass", "1 Camera 2", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        action1_Camera_3->setText(QApplication::translate("CameraClass", "1 Camera 3", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        action1_Camera_4->setText(QApplication::translate("CameraClass", "1 Camera 4", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        action1_Camera_5->setText(QApplication::translate("CameraClass", "1 Camera 5", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        action1_Camera_6->setText(QApplication::translate("CameraClass", "1 Camera 6", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        action2_Camera_1->setText(QApplication::translate("CameraClass", "2 Camera 1", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        action2_Camera_2->setText(QApplication::translate("CameraClass", "2 Camera 2", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        action2_Camera_3->setText(QApplication::translate("CameraClass", "2 Camera 3", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        action2_Camera_4->setText(QApplication::translate("CameraClass", "2 Camera 4", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        action2_Camera_5->setText(QApplication::translate("CameraClass", "2 Camera 5", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        action2_Camera_6->setText(QApplication::translate("CameraClass", "2 Camera 6", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        label_CCV->setText(QApplication::translate("CameraClass", "<html><head/><body><p><img src=\":/Camera/Resources/pictures/Camera View.jpg\"/></p></body></html>", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        menuFile->setTitle(QApplication::translate("CameraClass", "File", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        menuView->setTitle(QApplication::translate("CameraClass", "View", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
        menuCameras->setTitle(QApplication::translate("CameraClass", "Cameras...", 0, QApplication::UnicodeUTF8));
    } // retranslateUi

};

namespace Ui {
    class CameraClass: public Ui_CameraClass {};
} // namespace Ui

QT_END_NAMESPACE

#endif // UI_CAMERA_H
```

Comment: Try ui.actionCamera_Setup instead of actionCamera_Setup, because actionCamera_Setup is not a variable defined in Camera

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I was figuring out what I went wrong. The reason for ui.actionCameraSetup is because it is located in ui namespace?

Comment: Nope, ui is an instance of Ui_CameraClass, and it is a private member of Camera.

Answer (score 0):

`actionCamera_Setup` is a property of class `Ui::CameraClass`. In C++ you can access properties by name only if they are properties of the same class code belongs to, otherwise, you should access properties through object instance or pointer to object instance

```
instanceOfClassName.propertyName
```

or

```
pointerToInstanceOfClassName->propertyName
```

In your case `instanceOfClassName` is `ui` since there is a property `Ui::CameraClass ui` defined in `Camera` class.